# Sequelize connect to Postgres over Unix socket

Tags: node.js, postgresql, sequelize.js, unix-socket

I would like to connect to Postgres using Sequelize over Unix socket (not over `localhost`).

Postgres is configured to accept Unix socket connections from user `pgdba`. All works from command line with `psql`. So the Pg side is correctly configured.

I can't seem to find Sequelize configuration though to support Unix sockets. Closest I could find was for mysql, which I've adapted for Pg, but doesn't seem to work:

```
var sequelizeConfig = {
    dialect: 'postgres',
    dialectOptions: {
        socketPath: '/home/pgdba/data/5432/.s.PGSQL.5432',
    }
    port: 5432
};
var sequelize = new Sequelize('fooDb', 'pgdba', 'passwd', sequelizeConfig);
```

The error I'm getting when starting the app:

```
Unable to connect to the database: +23ms { [SequelizeConnectionError: pg_hba.conf rejects connection for host "127.0.0.1", user "pgdba", database "fooDb"]
  name: 'SequelizeConnectionError',
  message: 'pg_hba.conf rejects connection for host "127.0.0.1", user "pgdba", database "fooDb"',...
```

Apparently sequelize is still trying to go over `localhost` instead of the Unix socket and the `pg_hba.conf` is correctly rejecting it, as is configured. Is there a way to configure Sequelize for Postgres and Unix socket?

Using Sequelize 3.14.2 on Node v5.1.0 and Postgresql 9.5.0beta2.

Comment: I used the same config as you described and it worked like a charm! 

As I don't have a username or password for the db, I left those fields blank.

Comment: I used the socketPath with mysql and it worked for me but format for socketPath that we have to provide is /cloudsql/[instance_connection_name]. Here instance_conneciton_name you can find it inside cloud sql page below public ip address section.